# MySQL 2 columns NOT IN (One item array)

Tags: mysql

I have a query where column1 and column2 should not have value in an array.
The array is created from single values (user IDs) with 2 subqueries and union.

So far it look like this:

```
WHERE (`user`, `viewed`) NOT IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `role` = 3 UNION
    SELECT `user_id` FROM `groups_memberships` WHERE `group_id` = 3
)
```

This way it throws Cardinality error because it is expecting 2 values per item.
I know it can be done via separation of those 2 columns (`user`, `viewed`) but it would take 2 extra subqueries which is probably not the best solution.

Is there any other way how to filter out results where column `user` and column`viewed` are not in an array of user IDs???

Thanks

Comment: is there any relation between your user and groups_memberships tables?

Comment: groups_memberships is actually a table storing pairs group_id -> user_id

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
WHERE (`user`, `viewed`) NOT IN (
    SELECT `id`,null as userid FROM `users` WHERE `role` = 3 union
    SELECT null,`user_id` FROM `groups_memberships` WHERE `group_id` = 3
)
```

Comment: seems like its working but will confirm later, after more testing